# How to use hashmap in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a hash map I want to use it in javascript. So I thought of converting it into javascript map..how to use it or to do?

Comment: As urgent as it may be, without context it is very difficult to provide useful feedback. There are differences between a Javascript object and a traditional "Map". Can you describe what you intend on storing in the javascript representation and how you intend on referencing the values?

Answer (score 6):

Turn it into an object literal...

```
var map = {
   'a' : 'a',
   'b': 'b'
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use Associative Arrays, for example:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr["One"] = 1;
arr["Two"] = 2;
arr["Thr"] = 3;
arr["For"] = 4;

for(var i in arr)
{
    alert('Key='+i + ', Value = '+arr[i]);     
}
```

Comment: There are no associative arrays in ECMAScript.

Comment: Your code works because `Array`s are also objects. You shouldn't use arrays in this manner.